# Ip Range control on c#

Tags: c#, ip

I have an IP range which is formed "from" and "to"

From: 127.0.0.1  to: 127.0.0.255 etc.

How can I control the sended Ip which is 127.0.1.253? Is it inside of Ip range?

Comment: Does your IP address range have to be stored as a 'from' and a 'to'? Are you able to store it as a network address, e.g. 127.0.0.0/24? That lends itself to range checks better.

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614003/restricting-an-ip-if-it-is-between-an-ip-range

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**Convert the IPs to an integer**](http://www.smartconversion.com/unit_conversion/IP_Address_Converter.aspx), and check whether it fits within the range.

- 127.0.0.1 = 2130706433
- 127.0.0.255 = 2130706687
- 127.0.1.253 = 2130706941

Hence it doesn't fit within the range.

---

```
 public static long IP2Long(string ip)
   {
       string[] ipBytes;
       double num = 0;
       if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip))
       {
           ipBytes = ip.Split('.');
           for (int i = ipBytes.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
           {
               num += ((int.Parse(ipBytes[i]) % 256) * Math.Pow(256, (3 - i)));
           }
       }
       return (long)num;
   }
```

*Source: http://geekswithblogs.net/rgupta/archive/2009/04/29/convert-ip-to-long-and-vice-versa-c.aspx*

---

Therefore using this method you could do something like:

```
long start = IP2Long("127.0.0.1");
long end = IP2Long("127.0.0.255");
long ipAddress = IP2Long("127.0.1.253");

bool inRange = (ipAddress >= start && ipAddress <= end);

if (inRange){
  //IP Address fits within range!
}
```